# How can I fix the error that didSelectItemAt function for UICollectionView showing wrong item (only showing first item)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to build an app, and there is a view which shows list of soccer leagues in collection view. I've setup Firestore database to store the require data and use the following codes to retrieve them into my app.

```
enum LeagueListType {
    case leagueList(viewModels: [LeagueCellViewModel])
}

class LeaguesViewController: UIViewController {

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var leagues = [LeaguesInfo]()
    private var sections = [LeagueListType]()

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(
        frame: .zero,
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, _ -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            return LeaguesViewController.createSectionLayout()
        })

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Leagues"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        configureCollectionView()
        fetchData()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }

    private func configureCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self,
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.register(LeagueListCollectionViewCell.self,
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: LeagueListCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }

    private func configureModels(leagues: [LeaguesInfo]) {
        self.leagues = leagues

        // Configure Models
        sections.append(.leagueList(viewModels: leagues.compactMap({
            return LeagueCellViewModel(id: $0.id,
                                       name: $0.name,
                                       logo: URL(string: $0.logo))
        })))

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        db.collection("leagues").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No league data")
                    return
                }
                self.leagues = documents.compactMap { (documentSnapshot) -> LeaguesInfo in
                    let data = documentSnapshot.data()
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let logo = data["logo"] as? String ?? ""
                    let leaguess = LeaguesInfo(id: id, name: name, logo: logo)
                    self.configureModels(leagues: [leaguess])
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    return leaguess
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is cellForItemAt part.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let type = sections[indexPath.section]
        switch type {
        case .leagueList(let viewModels):
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: LeagueListCollectionViewCell.identifier,
                                                                for: indexPath) as? LeagueListCollectionViewCell else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
            let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]
            cell.configure(with: viewModel)
            return cell
        }
    }
```

And I use the following codes for didSelectItemAt function in extension.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let league = leagues[indexPath.row]
        let vc = LeagueViewController(league: league)
        vc.title = league.name
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

The problem is that didSelectItemAt always returning wrong item. It's only showing viewcontroller for the first item of the leagues no matter which item I select.
Could you please enlighten me how to fix it?

Comment: Why `self.configureModels(leagues: [leaguess])`? I don't understand why you call it since, you do in it `self.leagues = leagues`, and also a new `collectionView.reloadData()`. You should call `collectionView.reloadData()` only once the `compactMap()` is done, no? And what's the code of `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've deleted `collectionView.reloadData()` in `fetchData()` part. But if I delete `self.configureModels(leagues: [leaguess])` or `self.leagues = leagues`, the list of leagues is not shown anymore.
I've added `cellForItemAt` part to my question. Could you please check it?

Comment: For a cell in cellForRow, you do `sections[indexPath.section]; switch type{.leagueList(let viewModels): let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]`. Well, do the same logic in didSelect.

Comment: I followed your instruction and it's solved now. Thank you so much, @Larme